# How to create materialized view log in postgreSQL?I got syntax error near on in the given query

Tags: postgresql

I tried code given below :

```sql
create materialized view log on payment
with primary key
including new values;
```

Syntax error near on in this code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no materialized view log in PostgreSQL.

To translate it into Oracle terms, PostgreSQL only has materialized views that are `REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND`, so you don't need a materialized view log.

You will have to write something more complicated with triggers to translate the unspecified Oracle materialized view to PostgreSQL.

Comment: will you please give any example for this complicated query where i have to use trigger to translate the unspecified materialized view to postgreSQL?

Comment: How could I give an example for something I don't know?